# onPause instead of onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-activity

Having read about the importance of saving non-UI information at the `onPause` point I am attempting to replace the code I am using for `onSavedInstanceState` with code for `onPause`.
So I have this code that is saving and restoring an `ArrayList` as part of the `savedInstanceState`:

```java
public class SetUpPlayers extends Activity implements OnClickListener 

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.set_up_players);

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
                setUpArrayList = (ArrayList<SetUpListItem>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("setUpArrayList");
    else 
                ...

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     savedInstanceState.putSerializable("setUpArrayList", (Serializable) setUpArrayList);
     super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);    
}
```

How can I use `onPause` to add my serialized `ArrayList` to the `savedInstanceState` that `onCreate` will pick up? Or will I need to save and load it from preferences instead?

Comment: Could you post the SetUpListItem code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already saving your `setUpArrayList` in the instance state Bundle. This Bundle will be passed to your activity in `onCreate()` and in `onRestoreInstanceState()` whenever this instance of the Activity is recreated. This will happen if your application goes to the background and Android kills the process hosting your application and then the user returns to your application (either by launching it again or by selecting it from the "recent tasks" list).

However, if the user exits your activity (by using the BACK button, for example) and then launches your activity again, the instance state passed to `onCreate()` will be null. If you also want to be able to restore `setUpArrayList` in this case, then you will need to store it in some persistent storage (database, shared preferences, etc.). In this case you can just serialize `setUpArrayList` to a `String` and write that in persistent storage (or you can use a more structured approach, like XML or JSON). You should do this in `onPause()`. Then, in `onCreate()` you can restore `setUpArrayList` from the persistent storage if the instance state argument is null.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed it so is serialized to persistent storage and will check out JSON.